# Understanding React Router nested sub routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to build an application with nested routing but I am struggling with going from a child page to its parent. A rough layout of the app:

```
Navbar
- '/' -Home
- '/templates' - Templates
-- '/templates/{id} - View
--- '/templates/{id}/edit - Edit
```

Switching between Home and Templates works fine, as does going from Edit to Home. But going from Edit to Templates results in a URL of /templates/{id}/templates.

A rough layout of my app:

```
<Nav> 
  <Main>
    <Templates>
      <DataTable />
      <Edit />
    </Templates>
  </Main> 
</Nav>
```

Main includes the following switch:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
  <Route path='/templates' component={Templates} />
  <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Nav contains link built this way:

```
class DrawerLink extends React.Component {
  renderLink = itemProps => <Link to={this.props.link} {...itemProps} />;

  render() {
    const { display } = this.props;
    console.log(this.props.link);
    return (
        <ListItem button component={this.renderLink}>
            <ListItemText primary={display} />
        </ListItem>
    );
  }
}
```

The Templates component then includes this switch:

```
<Switch>
  // Gets a query component which then renders DataTable
  <Route exact path={`${props.match.url}`} component={GetTemplates} />
  // View will go here once it is built
  // Gets a query component which then renders Edit
  <Route exact path={`${props.match.url}/:templateId/edit`} component={GetTemplate} />
</Switch>
```

DataTable also contains the Link to go to the Edit page, this link is built the same way as the links in Nav.

Comment: navigating to 'templates' will result in adding '/templates' to current url:
`eg. www.example.com/templates/1/edit -> www.example.com/templates/1/edit/templates`
navigating to '/templates' will result in changing url up from domain:
`eg. www.example.com/templates/1/edit -> www.example.com/templates`

Comment: Well, that is upsettingly simple. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Happens to everyone :) np

Answer (score 1, accepted):

navigating to 'templates' will result in adding '/templates' to current url:

```
eg. www.example.com/templates/1/edit -> www.example.com/templates/1/edit/templates
```

navigating to '/templates' will result in changing url up from domain:

```
eg. www.example.com/templates/1/edit -> www.example.com/templates
```